# Trying to write a powershell script that shows all locked files with computer names instead of IP address

Tags: windows, powershell, dns, hostname

The task given was to create a way for our staff to see who has the file open that they want to use, as Windows says it is either locked and doesn't name the person who has it locked, or it displays the person who made the file but not the person who currently has it open.

I can look it up in Computer Management on the fileserver, but were are hoping to speed up this for the end users.

I've written this powershell script on our fileserver and it works perfectly, I have this running every 5 minutes in Task Scheduler with administrative permissions:

```
get-smbopenfile -ClientUserName * |select clientcomputername,clientusername,path | Out-File -Encoding utf8 "S:\LockedFiles.txt" -width 300
```

The output looks like this:

```
clientcomputername clientusername               path                                                                                                                                                                                        
------------------ --------------               ----                                                                                                                                                                                        
IPADDRESS          DOMAIN\USERNAME              S:\FOLDER\FILE.FILEEXTENSION
```

What I really want to do now is get the computer name rather than the IP address, just in case staff are logged into multiple machines at the same time.

I wondered if *ClusterNodeName* or *PSComputerName* would provide this, but the returned data is always blank.

I thought about this and below is one option (the first line is pseudocode), but as I see it that would mean recursively altering the piped data or reading in piped data, which I'm not even sure how to do.

```
$ipaddress = IPADDRESS
$Workstation = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($ipaddress)
Write-Host $Workstation.HostName
```

Anyone have any ideas on how I can do this? Is there a better way?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to modify that object (maybe add a new property to it) that transforms the IP Address of the `clientcomputername` property to it's hostname. Is that right?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're looking to add a new property to your output object that has the resolved DNS Name from the IP Address found in the `ClientComputerName` property. For this you use [`Resolve-DnsName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dnsclient/resolve-dnsname?view=windowsserver2022-ps) to attempt the name resolution and a [`Try Catch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-7.3) in case it fails to capture the exception message. For the export I would recommend you to use [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7.3).

```
Get-SmbOpenFile -ClientUserName * | ForEach-Object {
    $dnsName = try {
        (Resolve-DnsName $_.ClientComputerName -ErrorAction Stop).NameHost
    }
    catch {
        [ComponentModel.Win32Exception]::new($_.Exception.NativeErrorCode).Message
    }

    [pscustomobject]@{
        ClientIpAddress  = $_.ClientComputerName
        ResolvedHostName = $dnsName
        ClientUserName   = $_.ClientUserName
        Path             = $_.Path
    }
} | Export-Csv "S:\LockedFiles.csv" -Encoding utf8 -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hi Santiago, that is excellent, just what we want, but unfortunately the DNS isn't resolving, it returns "DNS name does not exist" for all except for two terminal servers. However, when I use this code it works, so I assume it isn't a DNS issue: `code`$Workstation = [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName(IPADDRESS)
Write-Host $Workstation.HostName`code`

Comment: @Alex yep, that I figured. But it's not an issue with your code it's up to your DNS Server to resolve these IPs. If you know which DNS server can resolve them you can use the `-Server` on `Resolve-DnsName` (you can pass multiple DNS Servers to the cmdlet). But that is as far as I can help unfortunatelly

Comment: Ok, adding `code`-Server DNSSERVER1,DNSSERVER2`code` has resolved more of them. I realised also that my code mentioned in my previous comment was only returning the querying server (the fileserver).